# android different dimens not working

Tags: android, android-activity, dimensions, android-screen-support

I have four dimens.xml files in my values folder and I have different values for different dimens.xml files.
for example, in dimens.xml(hdpi) u_video_width is 306dp and dimens.xml(xhdpi)u_video_width is 404dp.but this values not working, because when i run my app in Nexus S (480X800) hdpi model genymotion

This is what my View looks like:

[![This is what my View looks like][1]][1]

As I said in hdpi dimens folder, I have 302dp but I have different width when I run my app (in XML activity file)
this is a my XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#D53362">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/u_video_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/u_video_height"
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is a my dimens xml files

[image: This is a my dimens xml files]

Nexus S has 480X800 resolution and i want to my VideoView to have 302dp in hdpi resolution and another resolution--another dpi how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Did you use your activity to check the dimen values? How do you know Nexus S got different values?

Comment: @FabinPaul  i have different dimens xml files

Comment: How do you know Nexus S got different values?

Comment: because i also tested my app different divices.Nexus 4,5 or etc @FabinPaul Paul

Comment: have you considered device screen size? Nexus S has screen size of 4" and Nexus 4 has screen size of 4.7" or the resolution of these devices?

Comment: @FabinPaul please see my first image.this is a hdpi screen and in hdpi screen's dimens i have width 306,but divice when i run my app has 480 screen size and is hdpi resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make same dimension appear the same on higher dpi devices android multiply these dimension with a constant ie

for mdpi it is 1x

hdpi    1.5x

xhdpi   2x

xxhdpi  3x

So in your case it is 306 * 1.5 = 459px

reset of the space (14dp ~35 px) is available on both sides of VideoView

Please refer [android developer page](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

At least this is what I understood. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, it seems it's working right. Your screen is 480px wide and your `VideoView` is 306dp(in a *hdpi* screen ~453px), and as it's *centered*, it remains a bit of margin.

If you want the same dp in another resolution, just remove `u_video_width` from the other files.

Comment: yes  nexus S has 480 width but in my videvoeiw has 306dp width

Comment: If you want the same dp in another resolution, just remove u_video_width from the other files What this mean ? can you explain me ? @user1934693

Comment: If you set 306dp, it'll be 453px in nexus s, from a total of 480px (320dp) screen width, that's ok?
What do you need? same width for VideoView in all devices, or same proportion in all devices?